# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded, but positive <Response [200]>

Tags: python, json, url

I'm going over some URL's and I can fetch most of the data I can from an API I'm using. *Imgur API. However when it finds an image that has been posted before but was eventually removed it still shows a positive URL get response (code 200), and when I use

```
    j1 = json.loads(r_positive.text)
```

I get this error:

```
http://imgur.com/gallery/cJPSzbu.json
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_poller_multiple.py", line 61, in <module>
    j1 = json.loads(r_positive.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

How can I "fetch" the error inside the j1 variable instead? I'd like to use a conditional structure to solve the problem and avoid my program from crashing. Something like

```
if j1 == ValueError:
  continue
else:
  do_next_procedures()
```

Comment: Your example URL gives me a 302 Found, redirecting me to http://imgur.com/cJPSzbu. Are you sure it's 200 OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `try` `except` instead:

```
try:
    j1 = json.loads(r_positive.text)
except ValueError:
    # decoding failed
    continue
else:
    do_next_procedures()
```

See [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the Python tutorial.

What *really* happens is that you were redirected for that URL and you got the image page instead. If you are using `requests` to fetch the JSON, look at [the response history](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) instead:

```
if r_positive.history:
    # more than one request, we were redirected:
    continue
else:
    j1 = r_positive.json()
```

or you could even *disallow* redirections:

```
r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False)
if r.status == 200:
    j1 = r.json()
```

Comment: As always, @martijn, brilliant advice, one of the fundamental Python flow of control structures. BTW congrats on the 100K!

Comment: Shouldn't `continue` be `pass` (Python's noop statement) instead? A `continue` statement outside a loop is SyntaxError on Python 2.7 (an exception-handling block is not a loop).

Comment: @rsanchezsaez: The OP has a `continue` statement, so I assumed the snippet posted is part of a larger block of code that loops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh I just noticed that, you are right. Nevertheless, I think that using `pass` for the exception handling example would make it more generally applicable for Python beginners. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The URL you listed redirects you to a HTML page. (Use `curl` to check things like this, he's your friend.)

The HTML page obviously cannot be parsed as JSON.

What you probably need is this:

```
response = fetch_the_url(url)
if response.status == 200:
  try:
    j1 = json.loads(response.text)
  except ValueError:
    # json can't be parsed
    continue
```